# Can't debug Ruby on Rails application in Netbeans 6.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, netbeans

Every time I try to debug my Rails app via Netbeans I get a ...

"Could not connect to web server - cannot show http://localhost:3000"

Rails - 2.3.5
Ruby - 1.8.7-p249

Anyone know how to resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: In NetBeans, hit CTRL+4 to open the Output window. That should help you see what error is happening when WEBrick tries to start.

Comment: I have the output window open ... shows nothing when I attempt to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to downgrade the ruby-debug-ide gem to 0.4.7.

See http://www.jetbrains.net/devnet/thread/283533

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your ruby platform? If I remember rightly when you install a new version of Netbeans it can set the default to JRuby. In 6.5.1 at least you'll find it under Tools->Ruby Platforms.

Comment: Yah I checked.  For the project I'm working on it is set to Ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [i686-darwin10]